# Awk, print only patterns that match the regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, grep

- For example i have this string:

```sh
 10.1.2.194 (197.84.211.148) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:01:44 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/web/images/refinements/loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 4178 0 1868 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/chevrolet/model/aveo/caryearrangeszar/2012/search?sort=PriceAsc&locationName=Cape%20Town&latitude=-33.92584&longitude=18.42322&county=Western%20Cape" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.4.66:8009"
```

I need to modify that in:

```sh
08/Oct/2015:09:01:44 GET /merlin-web-za/web/images/refinements/loader
```

How can i do it using awk or egrep?
- i tried commands below ,  But the result of first command shows full strings which contains both follow patterns

```sh
awk ' /08/Oct/2015:09:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{1,2}/ && /GET (/[a-z0-9-]{1,}){1,3}/'
```

and

```sh
cat file | egrep -o "08/Oct/2015:09:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{1,}.* GET (/[a-z0-9-]{1,}){1,}"
```

that fills the gaps between aforementioned patterns and as result i can see:

```sh
08/Oct/2015:09:01:44 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/web/images/refinements/loader
```

that is not exactly what i want to get

Comment: Try `awk '{a=$5" "$7" "$8; gsub(/[]["]|\.[^.]*$/, "", a); print a}'`

Comment: It seems your expected output needs revision, please check and let know if you actually want to obtain `08/Oct/2015:09:01:44 GET /merlin-web-za/web/images/refinements/loader.gif`, not `08/Oct/2015:09:01:44 GET /merlin-web-za/web/images/refinements/loader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
awk '{a=$5" "$7" "$8; gsub(/[]["]|\.[^.]*$/, "", a); print a}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/TCiUWY)

**Details**

The default field separator - whitespace - is used to split the line into fields.

- `a=$5" "$7" "$8;` - creates a variable by joining Field 5, 7 and 8 with a space
- `gsub(/[]["]|\.[^.]*$/, "", a)` - removes `[`, `]` and `"` and `.` + any 0+ chars other than `.` at the end of the string
- `print a` - prints the result.

However, the file you sent me contains comma+space separated IP addresses inside the first parentheses. You may use

```
sed -E -n 's/^[^][]*\[([^][[:space:]]+)[^][]*\][ \t]+"([[:alpha:]]+[ \t]+[^[:space:]]+).*/\1 \2/p' access_log > newfile
```

to get the results you want, namely, `time + Get/post +URL`.

**Details**

- `^` - matches start of string
- `[^][]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^][[:space:]]+)` - Group 1: 1+ chars other than `]`, `[` and whitespace
- `[^][]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - a `]` char
- `[ \t]+` - 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `"` - a `"` char
- `([[:alpha:]]+[ \t]+[^[:space:]]+)` - Group 2: 1+ letters, 1+ horizontal whitespaces and then 1+ chars other than whitespace
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The result is the concatenation of Group 1 and 2 values.

Comment: that works fine only for file with aforementioned string, but when i run your example with whole tomcat log, it doesn't print correctly

Comment: @АртемЧеремісін Then please show a part of the log where it does not work.

Comment: Note that this will fail for any URIs (the argument to `GET`) that contain a space.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zxDpOxz6pGf_veXBcbO_G1OyBENcwpKu

Comment: upd:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zxDpOxz6pGf_veXBcbO_G1OyBENcwpKu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @АртемЧеремісін What is the expected behavior for the URLs that do not end with a file extension like `10.1.2.194 (105.186.115.71, 54.240.147.77) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:01:41 +0000] "GET /merlin-image-server/view/70bf11f8-4c19-49da-8d38-2913f3d69c4c/800 HTTP/1.1" 200 41342 0 97882 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "ajp://10.1.3.201:8009"`?

Comment: no matter if there extension or not i just need a "time + Get/post +URL"

Comment: @АртемЧеремісін So, `/merlin-web-za/web/images/refinements/loader.gif` is OK for the OP log line?

Comment: @АртемЧеремісін Try `sed -E -n 's/^[ \t()0-9,.-]*\[([^][[:space:]]+)[^][]*\][ \t]+"([[:alpha:]]+[ \t]+[^[:space:]]+).*/\1 \2/p' access_log > newfile`. I opened the result in Excel and it seems to work.